# Calculation of feature vectors using HAAR feature extraction algorithm in Python

Tags: opencv, feature-extraction, haar-classifier

OpenCV has the implementation of HOG feature extraction algorithm.Can anyone tell me how can I get HAAR feature vectors in python?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is Open Source, you can (download and) read the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv):

Some source link maybe useful for understanding `Haar`:

1. [apps/traincascade/haarfeatures.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/apps/traincascade/haarfeatures.cpp)
2. [src/cascadedetect_convert.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect_convert.cpp)